# Convert sign in column names if not at certain position in R

Tags: r, regex

I have a couple of dataframe column names that I would like to modify. Specifically, I would like to remove the underscore if it's *not* at the position before the number at the end of the column name. For example, I have these column names:

```
learn_anx_1, learn_anx_2, learn_anx_3, job_anx_1, job_anx_2, Beh_Int2_1, Beh_Int2_2, anxty1_1, anxty1_2
```

And I would like to convert them to these:

```
learnanx_1, learnanx_2, learnanx_3, jobanx_1, jobanx_2, BehInt2_1, BehInt2_2, anxty1_1, anxty1_2
```

(So please note that the last two should stay the same because the underscore does only appear once at the end before the number!)

I hope this is clear. I'm just not very good with regex, but I believe that would be the best approach?

Thank you!

Comment: I believe this question should be **reopened** as it is not about removing the first underscore. A solution to OP could be to remove underscores preceeded by non-digits: `gsub("(?=_\\D)_", "", c("learn_anx_1", "learn_anx_2", "learn_anx_3", "job_anx_1", "job_anx_2", "Beh_Int2_1", "Beh_Int2_2", "anxty1_1", "anxty1_2"), perl = TRUE)`